# React Router v4 passing params to component

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I use React Router on MeteorJS projet, and i've create new slug type **/blog/:slug** url and my components for this url.

But, i don't know how i can passing a props params to my component (Ex. title, description, comment, etc.). I've test to show my console.log when i go to **/blog/test-slug** :

```
Object { path: "/blog/:slug", url: "/blog/test-slug", isExact: true, params: Object }
```

I do not have **params**.

You can see my routing :

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <main className="l-main">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route exact path='/blog' component={Blog} />
              <Route path='/blog/:slug' component={Article} />
              <Route path='/about' component={About} />
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

My Article component :

```
function Article(props) {
  console.log(props.match);
  return (
    <h1>{props.match.params.slug}</h1>
  );
}
```

And my link for acces to Article component :

```
<Link to={`/blog/${this.props.post.slug}`}>{this.props.post.title}</Link>
```

Anyone can help me about this ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 4):

solution 1: create proxy page component where you add your data.

```
<Route path='/blog/:slug' component={ArticlePage} />

const ArticlePage = ({ match }) =>
    <Article slug={match.params.slug} description="..." />

const Article = ({slug, description}) =>
    <h1>{slug} : {description}</h1>
```

Or, solution 2 : user render callback in Route component :

```
<Route path='/blog/:slug' render={({match}) => (
  <Article slug={match.params.slug} description="..." />
 )} />

const Article = ({slug, description}) =>
    <h1>{slug} : {description}</h1>
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case, i need to get my data in the route file ? I can't passing global object in params ?

Comment: Thanks for this it really helped me - its so hard to keep up with the changes to ReactRouter